# How do I singularize my tables in EF Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I prefer using singular nouns when naming my database tables.  In EF code first however, the generated tables always are plural.  My DbSets are pluralized which I believe is where EF is generating the names but I don't want to singularize these names as I believe it is more pratical to have them plural in code.  I also tried overriding the setting but to no avail.

Any ideas?  Here is my code and thanks.

MyObjectContext.cs

```
public class MyObjectContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
     public MyObjectContext(string connString) : base(connString)
     {
     }
     public DbSet<Product> Products {get;set;}
     public DbSet<Category> Categories {get;set;}
     //etc.

     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention>();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You've removed the wrong convention (*PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention*) for this purpose. Just replace your *OnModelCreating* method with the below and you will be good to go.

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.Edm.Db;
...
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

With Entity Framework 6, on your file that inherit from DbContext:

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Comment: The name changed from CTP5 to EF 4.1. This is now called DbModelBuilder.

Answer (score 3):

You can also change the property value:

On the Tools menu, click Options.
In the Options dialog box, expand Database Tools.
Click O/R Designer.
Set Pluralization of names to Enabled = False to set the O/R Designer so that it does not change class names.
Set Pluralization of names to Enabled = True to apply pluralization rules to the class names of objects added to the O/R Designer.

Answer (score 1):

The location of the definition of PluralizingTableNameConvention has moved to:

> `using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;`