# MvcScaffolding Keeps Pluralize DbSet item name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding

here is my model classes;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ContactFormWithMultipleCheckboxApp.Models {

    public class Product {

        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(50)]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }

    }

    public class Message {

        public int MessageId { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }
        [Required]
        //below one is to validate whether the e-mail address is legit or not
        [RegularExpression("\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And I have installed MvcScaffolding as nuget package to my app. I am trying to a simple scaffolding with following code;

```
PM> Scaffold Controller Message
```

it works and creates my controllers, views and DBContect class. but I have one problem. why does it pluralize my dbset item inside dbcontect class;

```
public class ContactFormWithMultipleCheckboxAppContext : DbContext
{
    // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
    // 
    // If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
    // automatically whenever you change your model schema, add the following
    // code to the Application_Start method in your Global.asax file.
    // Note: this will destroy and re-create your database with every model change.
    // 
    // System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ContactFormWithMultipleCheckboxApp.Models.ContactFormWithMultipleCheckboxAppContext>());

    public DbSet<ContactFormWithMultipleCheckboxApp.Models.Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

as you can see it creates the name as Messages but it uses Message on the other places like view and controller.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this blog post about MvcScaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/28/mvcscaffolding-one-to-many-relationships/) 0.9.4, Steve Sanderson writes:

> "Based on your feedback, controller
>   names are now pluralized by default
>   (e.g., you get PeopleController rather
>   than PersonController for a model of
>   type Person, unless you explicitly
>   enter PersonController as the
>   controller name when scaffolding)"

So by default (or convention) it pluralizes your names unless you tell it not to. You stated that you did that, and it didn't pluralize your controller or views.

I wonder if you also need to tell EntityFramework not to pluralize. See this post, ["How to singularize in EntityFramework"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796543/how-do-i-singularize-my-tables-in-ef-code-first) for more details about that.