# Entity Framework CodeFirst table pluralization

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I'm using CodeFirst of EF with a well defined Database.
My Database has a table named 'Centros' (Portuguese word) and I manage to find that EF tries to pluralize my entities to get a 'Centroes' witch is wrong in this case.

If I remove the pluralization `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();` i manage to get it to work BUT I have to rename my table to 'Centro' (to match my entity name).

In Portuguese 'Centro' is singular, 'Centros' is plural.

I don't want to rename my table names so how can I specify the matching table name for my entity after a remove the pluralization convention?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I annotate all my classes, regardless of whether the framework can do it for me through some smart reflection routines. E.g.

```
[Table("Order")]
public class Order
{

}
```

We can touch type, it's cleaner and it's less likely to fall over in some unexpected event.

Comment: This is the better answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796543/how-do-i-singularize-my-tables-in-ef-code-first

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do one at a time like this in Fluent API:

modelBuilder.Entity().ToTable("ContactInfo");

Answer (score -1):

ModelBuilder is now System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.