# pluralize table names in non-english language with entity framework 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, pluralize

Using asp .net mvc4, I want to have all my tables, views, controllers named in Italian language.
Using EF 5 Code First I get table names pluralized with english language rules, and this is bad.

Is there any place where to code custom inflection rules?
I usually use Ruby on Rails for web applications, which has a very nice way to deal with this issue.
Is there any similar feature in `Entity Framework 5`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the answer here to disable pluralization.

[How do I singularize my tables in EF Code First?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796543/how-do-i-singularize-my-tables-in-ef-code-first)

You can annotate your tables to specify the name also.

[Entity Framework CodeFirst table pluralization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712794/entity-framework-codefirst-table-pluralization)

Comment: Using DataAnnotation is the answer I was looking for. I don't want to disable pluralization, just be able to override it when i need.