# Entity Framework 5 renaming - Database First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm using Database First approach and I have table called `Campus` and when I add to my `edmx` from SQL Server and I see that it renamed to `Campu` why is that doing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your project is having some table pluralization problems. So when your table `Campus` is created, Entity Framework is literally reading it as an entity called a `Campu` that you have pluralized to be `Campus`.

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796543/how-do-i-singularize-my-tables-in-ef-code-first) on how to change pluralization.

But this isn't really a problem right? You can change your model name back to `Campus`.

Comment: its not a problem, i can change it back but if i re-create my model  it will re-generate my model back to `Campu` and again i have to rename back to `Campus` its frustration...