# Table name in code first approach is automatically changing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I have created a class name History with required columns and used the package manager console to update the database the thing that I have noticed is that the table in database created is Histories.

Wanted to know that how History to Histories got created.

Another table with Transactions created which is correctly created.

All the table name ending with y alphabets gets converted to ies would to understand where is such kind of logic written.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796543/how-do-i-singularize-my-tables-in-ef-code-first

Comment: Its convention (pluralizing the table name). Refer [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796543/how-do-i-singularize-my-tables-in-ef-code-first)

Comment: Helpful,understood thanks @Steve & Stephen

Answer (score 0):

If you add the annotation '[Table("YourTableName")]' to your table class, it should create your table in the db as what you named it and not "YourTableNames".

Like this:

```
[Table("MyTable")]
public class MyTable
```

Also, in your db context (i.e., ApplicationDbContext), you would usually pluralize the dbsets with type of  tablename tablenames. As in:

```
    public DbSet<TableName> TableNames { get; set; }
```

As mentioned in the comments, it's part of the conventions. Not sure if that explains it, but it should be a start.

Comment: Thanks for trying but the link added above by Steve & Stephen is very helpful.