# Why is the Entity Framework Table Name plural?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am learning Entity Framework Code First.
I have created a model class named 'Category', after running update-database i find that EF name the class 'Categories'.
My Model is as Follwoing.

```
public class Category
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [StringLength(maximumLength:50)]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You forgot to ask anything or describe an issue.

Comment: EF pluralizes table names by default. You can change that setting globally or individually. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796543/how-do-i-singularize-my-tables-in-ef-code-first).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I singularize my tables in EF Code First?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796543/how-do-i-singularize-my-tables-in-ef-code-first)

Comment: There are a ton of articles + other SO posts about this.  But, we can't really help you because we don't know if this convention is a problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework relies on various naming conventions used by the data context to understand the conceptual model. The entity name will be singular and the data set name will be plural, automatic migrations will create the table name as plural following the same convention.